# @Retryable e @Async com spring

Tags: java, spring, async, spring-boot

É possível criar um método assíncrono e que possa ser tentado novamente caso ocorra alguma exceção com spring?

```
@Retryable
@Async
public void myMethod() throws Exception {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Sim, qual o problema está tendo? Normalmente uso com `@Retryable` em um método separado e ele é chamado pelo método executado de forma assíncrona.

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer a execução assíncrona de um método e caso a execução falhasse seria feita uma nova tentativa, para conseguir isto criei duas classes a primeira com o método anotado com <code>@Async</code> e a segunda com o método <code>@Retryable</code> e apenas delego a função da primeira para a segunda classe.

Comment: Você esta tentando trabalhar com dois interceptadores ao mesmo tempo. Já pensou em separar a invocação da execução ?

Comment: Uma possível solução que imaginei foi separa em duas classes: uma com o Async que chama a outra com Retryable